# How to wait for document.write to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn, fallback

I am trying to write some script fall-back code so that if jQuery and jQuery Validator is not available from a CDN I load a local version. Note that the following script is in a separate file to support Content Security Policy (CSP).

```
(window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery.js"><\/script>'));
($.validator || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery-validate.js"><\/script>'));
```

If jQuery is not available a new script tag is written to the end of the document but then the next line errors saying that $ is undefined. How can I wait for the document write to finish loading up the document before executing the next line?

Comment: Removed [tag:jquery-validate] tag since the issue/question/solution has nothing in particular to do with this plugin and could apply to any CDN hosted script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should utilize the `onload` event of the `<script>`. Instead of `ducoment.write`, add a script tag to the document via DOM manipulation:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.onload = function() {
  // jQuery is now loaded and can be used
}
s.src = '/js/jquery.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

UPDATE:

The answer to your question 'how to wait for document.write' is you don't have to because `document.write` is synchronous. The next line after `document.write` will only execute once the write method finished writing. However, if you write a `<script>` tag into the document with an `src` attribute, the loading of the resource (where src points to) will be asynchronous and will start after write finished *in paralell* with the next statements. Because it's impossible to tell in advance how long the loading of a resource will take, the only viable approach to be sure everything is available from the external script is the `onload` event.

Answer (score 2):

`document.write` already blocks execution until the information is parsed and processed. So you don't require any extra code for your example.

On an other note, I would recommend to use DOM injection instead of `document.write`. `document.write` delays CSS processing and can cause a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) (Flash of unstyled content).

DOM injection can be done as follows:

```
var scriptElm = document.createElement('script');
scriptElm.src = '/js/jquery.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( scriptElm );

// Check if jQuery is loaded here
```

Comment: But at the point where your code's comment says "check if jQuery is loaded" the OP needs to wait for it to load. How do you do that?

Comment: So how come $ is undefined on the second line?

Comment: @RehanSaeed `$` is `undefined` until *the script has been loaded*. The `document.write()` call is finished successfully, but the script is not loaded yet when your second line is being executed